# Command to uncomment multiple lines without selecting them

Tags: emacs, comments, elisp

Is there a command in emacs to uncomment an entire comment block without having to mark it first?

For instance, let's say the point is inside a comment in the following code:

```
  (setq doing-this t)
  ;; (progn |<--This is the point
  ;;   (er/expand-region 1)
  ;;   (uncomment-region (region-beginning) (region-end)))
```

I would like a command that turns that into this:

```
  (setq doing-this t)
  (progn
    (er/expand-region 1)
    (uncomment-region (region-beginning) (region-end)))
```

It's fairly easy to write a command that (un)comments a single line, but I've yet to find one that uncomments as many lines as possible. Is there one available?

Comment: Multiple cursors is a nifty package:  https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el  You can go to the left of every line or the right of every line in the region, and simultaneously type or delete characters on multiple lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick reply --- code could be improved and made more useful.  You might want to extend it to other kinds of comments, besides `;;;`, for instance.

```
(defun uncomment-these-lines ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((opoint  (point))
        beg end)
    (save-excursion
      (forward-line 0)
      (while (looking-at "^;;; ") (forward-line -1))
      (unless (= opoint (point))
        (forward-line 1)
        (setq beg  (point)))
      (goto-char opoint)
      (forward-line 0)
      (while (looking-at "^;;; ") (forward-line 1))
      (unless (= opoint (point))
        (setq end  (point)))
      (when (and beg  end)
        (comment-region beg end '(4))))))
```

The key is `comment-region`.  FWIW, I bind `comment-region` to `C-x C-;`.  Just use it with `C-u` to uncomment.

Comment: @Drew If you feel like it, have a look at the variables `comment-start` and `comment-end` to make the code more general.

Comment: Yes, it could be improved in several ways, including optionally handling other kinds of comments besides `;;; ` at bol.  I don't have much use for such a command myself, but perhaps @BruceConnor will want to extend it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Emacs' comment handling functions to make a generalised version of Drew's command.

```
(defun uncomment-current ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-at-eol))
    (goto-char (nth 8 (syntax-ppss)))
    (uncomment-region
     (progn
       (forward-comment -10000)
       (point))
     (progn
       (forward-comment 10000)
       (point)))))
```

Comment: `forward-comment` "gives up" too easily; if point is not directly behind a comment, it doesn't seem to catch anything.  Assuming that the comment is the first non-whitespace on the line, this can be solved by adding `(beginning-of-line)` to the beginning of the excursion.

Comment: I'd use `uncomment-region`.  And I'd first move outside of the current comment with something like `(goto-char (nth 8 (syntax-ppss)))`.